# Codeception. Laravel Controller Dependency Injection

Tags: laravel, testing, dependency-injection, codeception

How do I replace `sendMessageService` in `CreateVacationCest` with a mock?

Controller

```
class BotController extends Controller
{
    private $sendMessageService;

    public function __construct(SendMessageService $sendMessageService)
    {
        $this->sendMessageService = $sendMessageService;
    }
}
```

Cest Class

```
class CreateVacationCest
{
    public function testVacationStatus(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->sendPOST('/test', ['message' => 'test']);
    }
}
```